# custom component not a known element

Tags: angular, components, ionic4

I have an easy component in ionic, app it is just a test, I created the component with the ionic cli
this is my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, RouteReuseStrategy, Routes } from 
'@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { ProfileService } from './services/user/profile.service';
import { AuthGuard } from '../app/services/user/authguard';
import { AuthService } from './services/user/auth.service';
import { ItemModule } from '../app/modules/item-module/item-module';
import { MyComponentComponent } from './my-component/my-component.component';
import { JustTestComponent } from './just-test/just-test.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyComponentComponent,
    JustTestComponent,
  ],
  exports: [],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    ItemModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    AuthService,
    AuthGuard,
    ProfileService,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

this is my component:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-just-test',
  templateUrl: './just-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./just-test.component.scss']
})
export class JustTestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

if I put the tag 
in a html page get this error:

```
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'app-just-test' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-just-test' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-just-test' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas'
```

I know this question has been asked many times, but as far I  could not see where is the problem,everything seems ok to me, 
my ionic version is 4.1.2,
this is my ng --version:

```
    Angular CLI: 6.1.5
Node: 10.0.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.1.7
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms, http
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.7.5
@angular-devkit/core              0.7.5
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.7.5
@angular/cli                      6.1.5
@ngtools/webpack                  6.1.5
@schematics/angular               0.7.5
@schematics/update                0.7.5
rxjs                              6.2.2
typescript                        2.9.2
webpack                           4.9.2
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

These are the steps I perform when I got such an error.

1. Verify that selector name is correct.(Check the selector defined in the component)
2. Verify that component is declared in the module
3. If it is in another module, import that module(If it is in another module you have to import the component to that module first.)
4. Restart the cli

And remember **You can't declare a component twice.**

Answer (score 1):

You have to put 
 `entryComponents: [JustTestComponent]` as well as you have it in declarations

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the `MyComponentComponent` in a module where you are trying to use this. It could be in your item.module or some other module.

Note : declaring in AppModule will not resolve the issue if you have multiple modules in your application.